# div layer to form input

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working with http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_geocoder_PointInPolygonChicago.html
I want to be able to get the results shown in  into a textbox, that way I can use it in a form,

---

I was able to do it with http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_sidebarA.html using:

**HEADER**-

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript>
function readText (form) {
TestVar =document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = fusiontabledata;
alert ("You typed: " + TestVar);
}

function writeText (form) {
form.area.value =document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = fusiontabledata 
}
</SCRIPT>(
```

**BODY**-

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="area" VALUE=""><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button2" Value="Write" onClick="writeText(this.form)">
```

---

but I can't seem to modify it correctly to work with the new example (see first link)
).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does _your_ code look like?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see this till now. thanks, anyway, I got it sorted as you can see below.
your website is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted, thanks for your help.

Header-

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function readText (form) {
TestVar =$('#neighborhood').text();
alert ("You typed: " + TestVar);
}

function writeText (form) {
form.area.value =$('#neighborhood').text();
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Body-

```
<form><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="area" VALUE=""><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button2" Value="Write" onClick="writeText(this.form)"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have a div with id `sidebar`, but `document.getElementById('sidebar')` tries to find it. So, you should change

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="area" VALUE="">
```

into:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="area" VALUE="" id="sidebar">
```

Comment: Thanks Olivia,, that code was for http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_sidebarA.html. however it uses reverse geocoding, and I couldn't get it to use a normal address.

I found http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_geocoder_PointInPolygonChicago.html, which does the search by address, but I can't seem to do the same, and get the info from the appropriate layer (navigationin that document.